# Combine 2 tables in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, join

I am making a Microsoft access data base to keep track of how much we owe different vendors. currently there is a tablet that stores my cost of operation each day for each day. this table has these rows. table name = A ID (key) vendor, total pay, rate, days, head count... total pay = (ratedaysheadcount)

I have written this sql to give me my data.

```
SELECT Sum([A].TOTALPAY) AS TEMPCharge, [A].VENDOR AS TempVENDOR
FROM A
GROUP BY VENDOR
ORDER BY VENDOR;
```

I have this tablet and i would like to blend it with another table that shows totals by vendors and store the results in the second table. this tablet (table B) has these rows Id, Vendor, totalPay ..... i would like to import my sql result to fill up the totalpay of table B. where it is matched by vendor. I looked at Insert INTO but i cannot use a where statement. any advice would be nice,

Comment: FYI: MS Access is not related at all to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This would get you a simple insert from Table_A to Table_B:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (Vendor,totalPay)`
SELECT VENDOR,SUM(TOTALPAY)
FROM Table_A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_B WHERE Vendor=a.Vendor)
GROUP BY VENDOR
```

If you are updating EXISTING records in Table_B:

```
UPDATE Table_B b
SET totalPay=totalPay+(SELECT sum(totalPay) from Table_A WHERE Vendor=b.Vendor)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A WHERE Vendor=b.Vendor)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am looking at doing an update, and i seem to still be getting errors when i used your code here. I get a syntax error missing operator in the second line